# How to create boxplot graph and same coloured spots around them

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a question about this kind of graph.

I'm interested on how to obtain/show the spots around the same coloured box.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Do you want the starts too?

Comment: If you'd like to show both of them, it would be ok to me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update on OP request:
[image]

The code:

```
library(ggpubr)


# create fake data mtcars1
mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% 
  add_row(mtcars[1,]) %>% 
  mutate(group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 11))

compare_means(disp ~ cyl, data = mtcars1,  method = "t.test")
my_comparisons <- list( c("4", "6"), c("6", "8"), c("4", "8") )

ggboxplot(mtcars1, x = "cyl", y = "disp", fill = "cyl", add = "jitter") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#0433ff", "#fe403f", "#66cd00")) +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons)+
  stat_compare_means(label.y = 700) +
  facet_grid(.~group, switch = "x")+
  xlab(NULL) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

Here is an example using the `ggpubr` package and the `mtcars` dataset:

```
library(ggpubr)

compare_means(disp ~ cyl, data = mtcars,  method = "t.test")
my_comparisons <- list( c("4", "6"), c("6", "8"), c("4", "8") )

ggboxplot(mtcars, x = "cyl", y = "disp", color = "cyl", add = "jitter") +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons)+
  stat_compare_means(label.y = 700)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you think it would be possible to use the same stylw of the picture I've published?

Comment: I ignore whether you read my message or not. By the way I was wondering whether it will be possible to use the same drawing features you can see in the picture I've posted. Specifically, I'm referring to the black border of the spots around the boxplot

Comment: Oh. I missed your first comment. Sorry for that. I will have a look on this! It might take some time.

Comment: Do not worry. Looking forward the update ;)

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: Pretty cool. Thanks. Do you thinnk that it will be possibele to make the spots and the boxplots in the same colour? Sorry I do not want to sound peculiar, it is just for learning